# does it sound natural?

Tags: meaning, tenses, indirect-speech

- "I'm British"
- I told the police I was British
- I told the police I am British

In the following situation "was" sounds more natural.
Then the police arrived... I told them I was British and they let me go.

In the following situation "am" sounds more natural (not sure why, just a hunch)

- Why didn't you tell us you were British?!!!!
- I told you I am British!

Am I right or wrong?

Comment: "I told you I was British" is grammatically fine but lacks the punch, the immediacy of "I told you I am British!" // "Why didn't you tell us you were British(!/?/!?)" sounds more upmarket /educated than "Why didn't you tell us you're British(!/?/!?)" (and using 'you are' in conversation would be rare).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth What happens if you say "I'm not British!"? Do you think they give you a good kicking?

Comment: Not while we're observing antisocial distancing.

Comment: See https://english4today.com/grammar-topic/tense-changes-with-reported-speech

Comment: Ok, consider this: I told them I am British. Question: Are you? Yes? Okay, then the sentence is right. //I told them I was British. The sentence is right for reported speech. //I told them I was British. [I no longer am] So, all three are right, they mean different things, slightly.

Answer (score 1):

The habit is to use *was* or *am* depending on when the event happened rather than when you are telling the story. The event was in the past so it gets the usage of the past. It is much the same as if you were telling us how hungry you told them you were. "I told them I was hungry." Even though you may have said to them "I am hungry."

Comment: Being hungry is a temprary state, being British is a permanent state.

Answer (score 0):

If you're specifically quoting what you told the police, you should say "I am British." If you're just talking about what information you passed onto the police at that moment, say "I was British."

Comment: No, it's not as simple as that, Barney. "I told them[,] 'I am British' " uses direct speech correctly, and one has to really contrive a situation where 'was' is the correct choice. But "I told them [that] I was British" and "I told them [that] I am British" (both indirect speech) are both fine, with (almost always) the same meaning, with perhaps different nuances of emphasis.